# The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp-tags

I am trying to display Data from DB.But Shows error as

> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from
>   fulfilling the request

Exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/pages/Detail.jsp at line 14

11: </head>
12: <body>
13: 
14: <c:forEach var="x" items="${prdt}">
15: <table>
16: <img src="resources/Images/${x.id}.png"/>
17: <td>"
```

## MY JSP

```
<c:forEach var="x" items="${prdt}">
<table>
<img src="resources/Images/${x.id}.png"/>
<td>
<c:out value="${x.product_Name}"/></td>
<td>
<c:out value="${x.descripction}"/></td>
<td>
<c:out value="${x.price}"/></td>
<td>
<c:out value="${x.mfg_Date}"/>
</td>
</table>
</c:forEach>
```

## My Controller

```
public ModelAndView productDtails(@PathVariable int id)
{   
ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("Detail");
model.addObject("prdt",pd.getById(id));
return model;
}
```

## My DAO IMpl

```
public Product getById(int id) 
{   
Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
Product p=(Product) session.get(Product.class, id);
session.close();
return p;
}
```

Any Idea????

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? Unrelated: your HTML is completely invalid. You can't pit images and tds directly inside a table element.

Comment: not exacly...we can use...Its Supports in HTML5

Comment: No, it's not. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element.

Comment: Bro I m sure abt it.Bcz Now only i Debug my Shopping cart webapp.Its Working

Comment: The *browser* tries to fix all your mistakes by displaying something. That doesn't mean your HTML is valid, i.e. respects the HTML5 standard specifications. Read them. Use an HTML validator. Learn the language properly.

Comment: hmm ok bro..Thanks for ur advise..I ll learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate over `prdt` object i.e., you are using `forEach` tag and `prdt` is not a `List` object, so to solve the issue simply remove `<c:forEach var="x" items="${prdt}">` or else you need to return a `list` object from your Contoller.

Your JSP looks as below (after removing `<c:forEach`):

```
<table>
<img src="resources/Images/${x.id}.png"/>
<td>
<c:out value="${prdt.product_Name}"/></td>
<td>
<c:out value="${prdt.descripction}"/></td>
<td>
<c:out value="${prdt.price}"/></td>
<td>
<c:out value="${prdt.mfg_Date}"/>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: But without defining var="x" how can we use "x.product_Name"..etc

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by adding the below in the model

```
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

C# MVC for POST