# JSTL forEach unable to print list values

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I am trying to forward a list to print in a .jsp page
But I am unable to get a proper output.

From Servlet

```
    request.setAttribute("bankStatements", transactionDetailsBeanList); 
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/displayBankStatement.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

.jsp file

```
   <c:forEach items="${bankStatements}" var ="bankStatement" >

   <tr><td>${bankStatement.transactionId}</tr></td>

  </c:forEach>
```

[Faulty values displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z8CY.png)

Comment: Are you specifying that c is jstl core at the top of your JSP file? Just a thought, my JSP skills are very rusty!

Comment: Are you trying to access the JSP directly? It's difficult to say anything without looking into your code. Follow [this working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62118682/displaying-map-in-tabular-format-which-has-object-as-key-and-arraylist-as-value/62119633#62119633).

Comment: I.e. <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Comment: @Chris It is present check the file here  https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp/blob/master/src/main/webapp/displayBankStatement.jsp

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Check this link..... jsp file-https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp/blob/master/src/main/webapp/displayBankStatement.jsp               the jsp file is being called from here (Check line 69)  - https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp/blob/master/src/main/java/BusinessLogic/DisplayBankStatement.java

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I am sure that the transactionDetailsBeanList in line 68 is not empty

Comment: Ah okay, it was just a bit of a guess on my part. Looks like someone has pointed you to a previous SO answer so hope that fixes it for you

Comment: @Chris I tried following the instructions in the second comment . I am unable to resolve the issue. Pls help

Comment: Ah, I'm pretty rusty as mentioned, I haven't worked with JSP for about 3 years. I'll have a quick look at your code when I get a chance to see if I can spot anything obvious, but don't be too optimistic!

Comment: Have you seen this question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25372735/2568649 I notice your web.xml uses the same docttype declaration. Maybe worth trying this other version. Also note the point about JSP caching, if you change web.xml do edit the JSP in some arbitrary way, else it won't get recompiled